# Call to a member function count() - I have faced the issue for View page showing error

Tags: laravel

Please check the below code for view and controller.

Controller:

```
$staffreply = StaffReply::where('ticket_id', '=', $ticketID)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

if ($staffreply->count()) {
    //Get the data values
} else {
    $staffreply = "";
    $supportstaff = "";
    $supportteam = "";
}

return view('pages/support/service-view',compact('data','staffreply','supportstaff','supportteam'));
```

View Page:

```
@if($staffreply->count())                 
    @foreach($staffreply as $supportDesk)
        <span>Posted on {{$supportDesk->created_date;}}</span>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Error:

> Call to a member function count() on int (View: --\htdocs\laravel\project\resources\views\pages\support\service-view.blade.php)

How to solve the issue.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Looks like `$staffreply` is indeed an integer

Comment: I have added the view page   @if($staffreply!="")  - issue solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support, after I have edited the view page code issue solved.

Edited Code

```
@if($staffreply != "")                 
    @foreach($staffreply as $supportDesk)
        <span>Posted on {{$supportDesk->created_date;}}</span>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: mark as correct or close

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not clear what `$staffreply` is. You can't use `count()` on non-Arrayables.

First make sure that `$staffreply` is in fact a collection in the controller. If not, the fallback in the `else` should probably equal an empty collection and not a 0. If so, in the view you wouldn't need to check `if $staffreply->count()`.