# Data fetch and listing issue faced in my Laravel project

Tags: laravel, ticket-system

I have developing the ticket system. First table data fetch and display the view page but reply result is showing the last records. How to solve this issue. Please support me.

### Controller

```
 $ticketdetails = TicketDetails::where('ticket_id', '=', $ticketID)
    ->orderBy('ticket_id', 'asc')->get();

 if($ticketdetails->count()){

        foreach ($ticketdetails as $ticketItem) {

        $ticketID   = $ticketItem->ticket_id;
        
        $reply_check = Reply::where('reply_ticket_id', '=', $ticketID)->count(); 
         
            if($reply_check!="")
                {
                  $reply = Reply::where('reply_ticket_id', '=', $ticketID)->first(); 
                }
       } //Close foreach
   }  // Close if loop   

   return view('view-ticket',compact('data','ticketdetails','reply'));
```

### View Page

```
   if($ticketdetails->count())

     @foreach($ticketdetails as $ticketdetails)

     <p>{{$ticketdetails->ticket_details}}</p>

      $replyid = $reply->reply_ticket_id;

      $ticketdetailsid = $ticketdetails->ticket_id;

      @php
      if($replyid==$ticketdetailsid) 
       {
      @endphp 
       <p>{{$reply->reply_ticket_comments}}</p>
      @php
       } 
      @endphp

    @endforeach    
  @endif
```

### Expecting View page- For example

Ticket Case : Printer not working

Reply:Restart Printer - this is first reply

Ticket Case : After restart same issue.

Reply:okay, we will check now -- this is second reply

### Display For view page

Ticket Case : Printer not working

Reply:okay, we will check now -- this is second reply

Ticket Case : After restart same issue.

Reply:okay, we will check now -- this is second reply

Note:Ticket case data display is correct but reply data only showing the last record.

Comment: you are setting `$reply` in a loop, so every iteration you are overwriting the value so it will only have the value of the last iteration ...

Comment: Okay, but I need to collect the $ticketID   = $ticketItem->ticket_id; that id's for search the reply table. how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `reply` as array and with each iteration push new value to that array. It will look like following

```php
 $ticketdetails = TicketDetails::where('ticket_id', '=', $ticketID)
    ->orderBy('ticket_id', 'asc')->get();

 $reply = [];
 if(count($ticketdetails) > 0){  
        foreach ($ticketdetails as $ticketItem) {

           $ticketID   = $ticketItem->ticket_id;
        
          // $reply_check = Reply::where('reply_ticket_id', '=', $ticketID)->count(); 
         
           //if($reply_check!=""){
             //Code change below
           $reply[$ticketID] = Reply::where('reply_ticket_id', '=', $ticketID)->first() ?? [];  
          // }
       } //Close foreach
 }  // Close if loop   

 return view('view-ticket',compact('data','ticketdetails','reply'));
```

`reply` will consist of all the records with matching `ticketID` found in `ticketdetails`

And in view page you can do following

```php
   @if(count($ticketdetails) > 0)

     @foreach($ticketdetails as $ticketItem) //Change in name of variable

      <p>{{$ticketItem->ticket_details}}</p>

      //You don't need to check for id as new reply array consist of all records mapped with ticket ID 
       
      @if(count($reply) >0)
        @if(count($reply[$ticketItem->ticket_id]) >0)
          <p>{{$reply[$ticketItem->ticket_id]['reply_ticket_comments']}}</p>
       @endif
      @endif
     @endforeach    
  @endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the code and data stored in $reply array. but view page showing the error message. "ErrorException
Undefined variable: reply.   $reply is undefined." how to solve the issue. please support me.

Comment: @SSarangi I have updated my answer. `reply` is declare before if condition so we pass array when condition is not met and in view we check whether `reply` array has count more than 0 if it does we  show `reply_ticket_comments`

Comment: I have updated the code but still showing the error in view page. ErrorException
Undefined variable: reply (View: E:\xamp\htdocs\laravel\project\resources\views\ticket\pages\case\ticket-view.blade.php)

Comment: In view file on which line do you have error? `reply` is initialized and passed to the view in compact. I have updated conditions in answer please check once.

Comment: error issue solved. I have follow your updated code. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I have faced another issue. If ticket ID not found in the reply table then view page error.

ErrorException
Undefined index: 3 (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\project\resources\views\pages\case\ticket-view.blade.php)

Data records is
ticket_id - 1 support team replyed.
ticket_id - 2 support team replyed.
ticket_id - 3 no reply record

Comment: push in `reply` if record exists using  [null coalescing](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_oper_null_coalescing) and in view add 1 more if condition `count($reply[ticketId])` before `ptag`.

Comment: Controller page result

Ticket id:1
Count:1
REPLY:reply test

Ticket id:2
Count:1
REPLY:reply mail test

Ticket id:3
Count:0


if(count($reply) >0)
   if(count($reply[ticketId]) >0)
       <p>{{$reply[$ticketItem->ticket_id]['reply_ticket_comments']}}</p>
   endif
endif  this syntax is correct?

Comment: Updated my ans for controller and view please check

Comment: yes I have updated, but showing the error in view page ErrorException
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\project\resources\views\pages\case\ticket-view.blade.php)

Comment: Please support me, I am stuck in this error..   Controller page result example Ticket id:1 Count=1 REPLY=Restart Printer, Ticket id:2 Count=1 REPLY=okay, we will check now, Ticket id:3 Count=0 REPLY=.  The view page check the Ticket id:3 and going to Error (Undefined index: 3 ) <p>{{$reply[$ticketItem->ticket_id]['reply_ticket_comments']}}</p>

Comment: Please check the use cases and syntax declarations of `count()`, you are using it wrong in `reply_check` i have updated code please check `controller` and `view`.

Comment: always check variables to be collections before using `count`. Take a look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73413504/7006384)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the support.
I have stored the reply count in array variable $reply_display[ ] =$reply_check;  Then view page check the array values

```
      @php 
      $replyck = $reply_display[$i];
      if($replyck==1){  @endphp 
        <p>{{$reply[$ticketItem->ticket_id]['reply_ticket_comments']}}</p>  
      @php  }  
       $i = $i+1;
      @endphp
```

:)- my error issue solved.